# How to use generics to solve casting issue

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following scenario:

```
public interface IParam
{
    Object Value {get;set;}
} 

public abstract class BaseClass: IParam
{
    public virtual object Value {get;set;}
}

public class IntSubClass:BaseClass
{
    public override object Value {get;set;}
}
```

To the outside world, this interface is exposed. All properties are accessed via IParam. The drawback of this approach is a lot of casting issue.

```
IParam dummy = ParameterList[abc];
int index = (int)dummy.Value;
```

Request please advise how this problem can be solved using generics. To the outside, I can only expose generic interface.

Comment: Can `ParameterList` contain `IParam` objects that have `Value`s of different types?

Comment: Yes this list is composed of parameters of different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume the parameters can be of different types, then simply: no.

Oh, you can introduce generics... but that just changes things from

```
int val = (int)(paramList["abc"].Value);
```

to:

```
int val = ((IParam<int>)paramList["abc"]).Value;
```

doesn't really help much. The only other option is implicit conversion operators, which a: don't work on `interface`s, and b: are not very clear / obvious.

Frankly, I'd just use the cast. It isn't a problem. A box/unbox is not hugely expensive, and the code is clear in its purpose.

Comment: I agree Marc but this casting will never assure the type safety which may lead to run time errors. Please advise how can i assure type safety if i have use this object type based classes.

Comment: @dev389 you can't. Any other option just shifts the same type safety issue somewhere else. No matter whether this is .e. the `(IParam<int>)` cast, or the operator usage, or a method such as `GetInt32`, you ***cannot*** remove the issue of the code needing to ask for the right type of data. The only way to "assure" that is by using unit/integration tests.

Comment: ok Marc, i understand there is no way out. Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `IParam<T>` interface that has a `T Value {get; set;}` method. Is that going to solve your problem? You won't be able to cast to IParam, but rather pass the proper IParam around/

Comment: Correct. But in my case, IParam<T> is not generic i.e.  I have to use concrete type like IParam<int> to use it and parameter list is composed of different types also.

Comment: You can derive IParam<T> from an empty IParam, but you really don't get anything there. Use the typecast, as @Marc suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If on the inside you must hold parameters of all types together in one list, then, well, you can access them only by their common base type.

You could, on the inside, hold parameters in separate lists, each of a certain type, but that'd probably be an overkill in your scenario.